Remove the zero values from a raster using Python
I am trying to remove all the 0 value pixel from the raster, but whenever I am trying to do, 0 values still exist.
I am mainly trying to do is, I have 4 raster in a folder. I have to pick all the no data from each raster and create a mask of no data. Then I have to change the value of NO Data mask raster like, wherever the no data is there the value should be 1 and the 1 value should be no data. Then changing value raster should multiply with each raster of folder. So, I create like, user input their folder path and the final output should be saved under that folder with the name output-folder, But it will not working.
Below is my code snippet:
import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from osgeo import gdal

def merge_null_values_images(input_folder, output_folder):
    # Ensure the output directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # List all the tif files in the input folder
    tif_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith('.tif')]

    # Read each image and collect null values
    null_values = []
    for tif_file in tif_files:
        with rasterio.open(os.path.join(input_folder, tif_file)) as src:
            data = src.read(1, masked=True)
            null_values.append(data.mask)

    # Combine null values
    combined_null_values = np.zeros_like(null_values[0])
    for null_value in null_values:
        combined_null_values = np.logical_or(combined_null_values, null_value)

    # Create a new raster with combined null values
    first_tif_path = os.path.join(input_folder, tif_files[0])
    with rasterio.open(first_tif_path) as src:
        profile = src.profile
        profile.update(count=1, dtype='uint8', compress='lzw')

        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, "all_mask.tif")
        with rasterio.open(output_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(combined_null_values.astype('uint8'), 1)

def replace_values(input_raster_path, output_raster_path):
    # Open the raster file for reading and writing
    with rasterio.open(input_raster_path) as src:
        # Read raster data as a numpy array
        raster_array = src.read(1)

        # Replace 0 values with 2
        raster_array[raster_array == 0] = 2

        # Get metadata of the input raster
        kwargs = src.meta

        # Write the modified array to a new raster file
        with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            dst.write(raster_array, 1)

def further_replace_values(input_raster_path, output_raster_path):
    # Open the input raster
    input_raster = gdal.Open(input_raster_path)

    # Get raster band
    band = input_raster.GetRasterBand(1)

    # Read raster band as numpy array
    array = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32) # Convert the array to float32

    # Replace values
    array[array == 1] = np.nan
    array[array == 2] = 1

    # Set nodata value
    band.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)

    # Create output raster
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    output_raster = driver.Create(output_raster_path, input_raster.RasterXSize, input_raster.RasterYSize, 1, band.DataType)

    # Write array to output raster
    output_band = output_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    output_band.WriteArray(array)

    # Set projection and geotransform
    output_raster.SetProjection(input_raster.GetProjection())
    output_raster.SetGeoTransform(input_raster.GetGeoTransform())

    # Close rasters
    input_raster = None
    output_raster = None

def select_values_ge_1(input_raster_path, output_raster_path, nodata_value=-9999):
    # Open the input raster
    with rasterio.open(input_raster_path) as src:
        array = src.read(1)
        
        # Set 0 values to the specified NoData value
        selected_array = np.where(array == 0, nodata_value, array)

        # Get metadata of the input raster
        kwargs = src.meta

        # Update metadata to set NoData value and change data type to float
        kwargs.update(dtype=rasterio.float32, nodata=nodata_value)

        # Write the selected values to a new raster file
        with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            dst.write(selected_array, 1)

def multiply_rasters(input_folder, output_raster_path, output_folder):
    # Open the output raster
    output_raster = gdal.Open(output_raster_path)
    output_band = output_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    output_array = output_band.ReadAsArray()

    # Create output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Iterate over files in input folder
    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if filename.endswith(".tif"):  # Assuming all input files are TIFF
            input_raster_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
            input_raster = gdal.Open(input_raster_path)
            input_band = input_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
            input_array = input_band.ReadAsArray()

            # Multiply input raster with output raster
            result_array = input_array * output_array

            # Save result to new folder with same name ending with "same_area"
            output_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_same_area.tif"
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename)

            # Create output raster
            driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
            result_raster = driver.Create(output_path, input_raster.RasterXSize, input_raster.RasterYSize, 1, input_band.DataType)

            # Write array to output raster
            result_band = result_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
            result_band.WriteArray(result_array)

            # Set projection and geotransform
            result_raster.SetProjection(input_raster.GetProjection())
            result_raster.SetGeoTransform(input_raster.GetGeoTransform())

            # Close rasters
            input_raster = None
            result_raster = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = input("Enter the input folder containing all the images: ")
    output_folder = os.path.join(input_folder, "output_result")

    # Step 1: Merge null values in images
    merge_null_values_images(input_folder, output_folder)

    # Step 2: Replace values in the merged null values raster
    input_raster_path_1 = os.path.join(output_folder, "all_mask.tif")
    output_raster_path_1 = os.path.join(output_folder, "value_changed.tif")
    replace_values(input_raster_path_1, output_raster_path_1)

    # Step 3: Further replace values in the raster from step 2
    input_raster_path_2 = output_raster_path_1
    output_raster_path_2 = os.path.join(output_folder, "value_changed_2nd.tif")
    further_replace_values(input_raster_path_2, output_raster_path_2)

    # Step 4: Select values >= 1 in the raster from step 3
    input_raster_path_3 = output_raster_path_2
    output_raster_path_3 = os.path.join(output_folder, "value_selected_ge_1.tif")
    select_values_ge_1(input_raster_path_3, output_raster_path_3)

    # Step 5: Multiply the final raster with input images
    multiply_rasters(input_folder, output_raster_path_3, output_folder)

    print(f"Final output saved in {output_folder}")


That's not a snippet of code, there's way to much to read/debug, please condense it down to just the bit where you do the read/find & replace 0/write. I'm a little bit confused as to what you're trying to do.. is 0 the same as NoData for each raster? It's not clear from your description. What data type are your input rasters? I saw at one point you're casting to Float32, that would make true 0 hard to find in your array. Is your mask a new raster? Why replace 1 with NaN and 2 with 1? Try to stay well away from NaN, not every raster can store that value so it would revert to 0.

Please look into the select_values_ge_1 function, I have to change the value 0 to no data, but when output came it show 0 is there. I want to delete the the pixel containing 0 values.

What is the datatype when you try to update pixels with value 0 to have a value -9999? Does the datatype support negative integers? Is that update what you mean by deleting pixels? You cannot really remove pixels from the raster, only to mark them to mean nodata either by the nodata metadata or by a mask layer.

Perhaps let go of the selected_array concept and modify the array[array < 1] = nodata_value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425471/replace-numbers-below-threshold-in-numpy-array-with-zeroes is a good reference for this type of operation, that way the array retains the correct geometry (rows and columns). Because your selected_array has holes the missing pixels are being filled by 0's.

This is one liner expression in raster calculator Con(r1!=0,1)×Con(r2!=1,1) etc

@FelixIP I don't want to use raster calculator, I am doing in python

Can we delete the pixels that have the value 0??

Logic is the same, multiply 4 masked arrays

You can't delete pixels, the numpy array still has the same number of rows and columns, the gaps you create by deleting 0's will be interpereted as 0 when you write the array to a new raster.
